# How to get Java in Monodevelop?

Tags: java, ide, download, monodevelop

I know that MonoDevelop comes with IDEs for C and C# (among others), but how would I get Java as well? Assuming I'm on a 64-bit Windows machine.

Thanks

Comment: Just use a Java IDE. (Like Netbeans, Eclipse, or IntelliJ.) Java isn't really relevant to Mono / .NET

Comment: Is there any way? I know I can download a seperate IDE, but I would prefer an all-in-one IDE.

Comment: There probably isn't really a target market for such a product, seeing as Java and .NET are competing "full stack" platforms with little in terms of complementing one another. (I.e. it's unlikely that a single system would want to use both.) I recall Omnicore making IDEs for both based on the same foundation, but that company seems defunct nowadays.

Comment: Alright. I guess I'll have to stick to eclipse. I'll wait a bit though for someone else to answer; you never know, someone might know a trick.

Answer (score 3):

There is some support for Java in Mono using IKVM.NET. Take a look at the [http://www.mono-project.com/Java](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/extras/JavaBinding)

There is also a plugin for Java in MonoDevelop - https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/extras/JavaBinding, using IKVM.NET as well. You can try to build it and check how it goes.

Keep in mind that the purpose of IKVM.NET is to run Java code on top of .NET framework, so it will be "another Java" at least.